# sbt-eclipse unresolved exception

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

1. In PROJECT/plugins.sbt:

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbtsclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
   ```
2. In PROJECT/build.sbt:

   ```
   name := "FileSearcher"

   version := "0.1"

   scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
   ```
3. sbt version : 0.13.1

Below is an error I am getting:

> [error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: 
> com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbtsclipse-plugin;4.0.0: not found 
> [error] Could not create Eclipse project files: 
> [error] Error evaluating task 'scalacOptions': error 
> [error] Error evaluating task 'externalDependencyClasspath': error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was due to a typo:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.**sbteclipse**" % "**sbtsclipse-plugin**" % "4.0.0")
```